# Find text behind a line of code

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this line of code. By using that line of code it replaces a whole long text, which simplify my code. How from that line can I retrieve the text that is somewhere in my trunk?

```
<? php echo $this->article->description ?>
```

Comment: `$this->article` most likely refers an to Article model.  Trace back where that property is being defined.  Research MVC to understand the Model View Controller type frameworks if you don't understand what a model is.

Comment: I understand that, my problem is that I have a problem tracing it back. I can't find where it is being defined.

Comment: I don't know what you expect from us with one line of code presented then.  It's most likely defined in your controller...

Comment: please give some clarity where you are using this line..

Comment: exactly this line is is regarding codeigneiter framework